# How to make at operator while listing program?

Tags: listings, wolfram-mathematica

When I am inserting mathematica codes with the package `listing`, I find that it recognize at as a letter rather than an operator.

This comes into a result that, for example when typing `N@Table[10,5]`, the latex complier won't think that `N` and `Table` are keywords, but will check `N@Table` and conclude that this is not a keyword.

Otherwise I should tell mathematica "Insert a space arround `@`", but I do not know how to do this, either.

Codes:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Mathematica,frame=single]
N@Table
N @ Table
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

result:
[image]
Expected result: both `N` and `Table` in the first line are in bold face.

Comment: Without seeing you code, giving correct suggestion is not possible, please post the `MWE` of your code...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Sorry. I have added the minimum working code now.

Answer (score 1):

Now I solve this question.
This is hidden deeeeeeply inside the document.

An option named `alsoother` can be used here. (Note the last but two line.)
My Full code:

```latex
\lstdefinestyle{mma}{
    % backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    % basicstyle=\footnotesize,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    % breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    % breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    % captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{green!60!black},    % comment style
    % deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    escapeinside={`!}{!`)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    % extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    % firstnumber=1000,                % start line enumeration with line 1000
    frame=l,                           % adds a frame around the code
    % keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},       % keyword style
    language=Mathematica,                 % the language of the code
    morekeywords={Echo,FileNameJoin,Log10},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    % showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    % showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    % showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    % stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{purple!40!black},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    % title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
    alsoother={@,_},                  % Page 46 of document, make these into other (= operator)
}
```